# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'hotelName'

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, entity, oql

[This is table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo4Zu.png)

TblUser entity:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "hotelID", nullable = false)
private Integer hotelID;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "hotelName", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String hotelName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "addess", nullable = false, length = 250)
private String addess;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 250)
private String description;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "services", nullable = false, length = 250)
private String services;
@Column(name = "starLevel")
private Integer starLevel;
@Column(name = "phone", length = 20)
private String phone;
@Column(name = "isMain")
private Boolean isMain;
@JoinColumn(name = "Owner", referencedColumnName = "userID")
@ManyToOne
private TblUser owner;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "hotelAgent")
private Collection<TblHotel> tblHotelCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "hotelAgent", referencedColumnName = "hotelID")
@ManyToOne
private TblHotel hotelAgent;
```

Here is show.jsp

```
<c:set var="result" value="${requestScope.RESULT}"/>

    <c:if test="${not empty result}">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="result">
            The main hotel Name: ${row.hotelName}
            Address: ${row.address}
            Phone: ${row.phone}
            Star Level: ${row.starLevel}

            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>hotelName</th>
                        <th>addess</th>
                        <th>description</th>
                        <th>services</th>
                        <th>starLevel</th>
                        <th>phone</th>
                        <th>Owner</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="rows" items="${row.tblHotelCollection}" varStatus="counter">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${counter.count}</td>
                            <td>${rows.hotelName}</td>
                            <td>${rows.addess}</td>
                            <td>${rows.description}</td>
                            <td>${rows.services}</td>
                            <td>${rows.starLevel}</td>
                            <td>${rows.phone}</td>
                            <td>${rows.Owner}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>


        </c:forEach>
```

My class is public, all getter setter are implement. My libary is <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>, its ok. I spend few hour but don't know what is error.

Comment: Your `row` item isn't the class you think it is, apparently, but a String. `String` does not have a property names hotelName, thus the error is thrown.

Comment: oh, ty. I am so stupid. Thank you

Comment: now it show the error:  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: sample.entitys.TblHotel.tblHotelCollection, no session or session was closed. What is want to say, sir?

Comment: Initialize your lists in `EJB` before returning object containing them like this: `entity.getHotelCollection().size()`.